# How to fix hotkeys in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

bitbucket hijacks hotkeys and things just don't work how they supposed to.

(ctrl+f, ctrl+home, F3, etc.)

Is there any way to fix that?

(any idea why they do such a thing?)